# depth of ideal in polynomial ring

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a Noetherian local ring. Then the "depth" of an ideal $I$ measures the maximal length of regular sequence inside $I$. And $depth (R/I)$ measures the maximal length of regular sequence in the maximal ideal of $R/I$. So $depth(R/I)$ is zero if and only if the maximal ideal is an associated prime of $I$.

Now let $R=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ and $I$ be a homogeneous ideal. Is it true that $depth (R/I)$ is zero if and only if the homogeneous maximal ideal $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is an associated prime of $I$? is there a nice reference?

Comment: Are you taking the depth with respect to $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$? The associated primes are homogeneous and finite in number. Doesn't that do it?

Comment: This follows more or less from the definition since the minimal primes of a homogeneous ideal is homogeneous.